Is there an error in the Wikipedia graph of $\frac{\sin x}x$?
I was reading about the "sinc function" on Wikipedia and found the following graphs of $\dfrac{\sin x}x$ and $\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$.


Part of the normalized sinc (blue) and unnormalized sinc function (red) shown on the same scale

The graph suggests that the value of the function at the point $x=0$ is $1$. Although Wikipedia emphasizes $x\ne0$ several times, this is strangely not used in the graph above. I believe the graph should have a hole at the point $(0,1)$. Am I right or I am missing something?

how did you get 6782?

Both graphs should have a hole but the graphing software (i.e. desmos) does not always show it.

The caption says that these are the graphs of the (un)normalized sinc function which is defined as having value 1 at 0 in the same wiki article. I am guessing that the legend (confusingly) says $\sin(x)/x$ and $\sin(\pi x) / \pi x$ in order to distinguish between normalized and un-normalized sinc, because the same name is used for both.

If the single point $(0,1)$ were removed from the graph, you would not notice that it was missing, since a point has no dimension.

@RandyMarsh Thanks! Now I see that the legends of the graphs are actually misleading.

The function $f(x) = \sin(x)/x$ is not defined in $x=0$, but since $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(x)/x = 1$, we often let this function be $1$ at $x=0$ for it to be a continuous function on the whole real line.

To be more explicit: the function which is called $\operatorname{sinc}(x)$ is defined to be $\sin(x)/x$ for $x\neq 0$, and defined to be $\operatorname{sinc}(0)=1$.

$$z\to \text{sinc}(z)$$ is a symmetric, entier complex analytic function, like $z\to \cos(z)$, with the simple difference, that it's $\cos$ power series has the coefficients of the $\sin$-series
$$z \to \sum_{k=0}^\infty \ \frac{(-1)^k \ }{(2k+1)!}\ x^{2k} $$
There is no need to understand it as $ z \to \frac{\sin z}{z}$ apart from using the automatic differentiation schema of trigs and powers.
